# Extract timestamp from a gzip file

Tags: timestamps, gzip

How can I know the raw original timestamp of a file `foo` compressed with `gzip` without having to decompress `foo.gz`?

`gzip --verbose --list foo.gz` and `file foo.gz` will print formatted date and time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extract the timestamp manually. Assuming that the compressed file has a single member (this is normally the case with gzip):

```
<foo.gz dd bs=4 skip=1 count=1 | od -t d4
```

This prints the raw timestamp, i.e. the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC, in decimal.

Comment: $ dd bs=4 skip=1 count=1 if=foo.gz 2> /dev/null |   perl -nle 'print  scalar localtime unpack("i",$_);'  # Prints Sat Jul 13 12:21:10 2013 for 1373698270. Tested on win7/cygwin/perl